# maintain erection or maintain an erection?

Tags: articles

> He can only maintain an erection while laying on his back.
>
> He can only maintain erection while laying on his back.

I am not sure if both are okay in all situation or whether the second one is the most general and most appropriate here. The thing that confuse me is the lack of an article and the fact it's singular.

Comment: You shouldn't be confused by the ***lack*** of an article in this context, because idiomatically ***that article should normally be present***.

Comment: See [this NGram usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=problems+maintaining+an+erection%2Cproblems+maintaining+erection&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cproblems%20maintaining%20an%20erection%3B%2Cc0) for *problems maintaining **an** erection*, where the article-less form doesn't show on the chart at all (it just says *Ngrams not found: **problems maintaining erection***).

Comment: Source of quote please.  Where did you read or hear this sentence.

Comment: According to the [definition of erection](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/erection) in the dictionary, this word used in the sexual biology sense is always *countable* (marked with [C]), so the article is necessary when the noun is singular.

Comment: This question has created an image in my mind's eye that I am trying hard to get rid of.

Comment: Probably irrelevant to say that in many cases, a problem maintaining an erection is not purely a matter of hydraulics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing two usages here.

> He can only maintain an erection while laying on his back.

This is fine except that it should be lying, not laying as MichaelHarvey kindly pointed out in a comment, and it is singular because he can only have one erection at a time

> He can only maintain erection while laying on his back.

Perhaps you were thinking of

> He can only maintain erections while laying on his back.

This is now fine, it describes something habitual and repeated, he has problems standing up but lying down everything works OK.

Comment: Er, don't people _lie_ on their backs?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey good grief. How did I miss that?

Comment: Just change it.  Though there may be a bit of prevarication to disambiguate as well. :)